# Free Space After PostgreSQL Vacuum Not Showing In Server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I just ran pg_repack on a PostgreSQL production database which freed up 14 gigs of space, but the disk still shows the old space being used.

I'm using \l+ to check the database size -- this is where I see it is now 14 GB smaller, but the free disk space doesn't show in the command line when running: du -sh

Do I need to delete something else?